# Возможна ли продажа своей закрытой операционной системы на ядре linux?

Tags: linux, лицензирование

Допустим, ядро будет открытое, любой желающий сможет увидеть используемый код ядра и все внесённые изменения в него. Позволит ли gplv2 закрыть исходный код остальной системы и продавать её, если все остальные компоненты: чужие с закрытым кодом, чужие под лицензией типа bsd/mit/apache2, собственные написаны исключительно под этот продукт закрытые и под лицензией типа bsd/mit/apache2?

Пытаюсь понять, почему в таких решениях обычно применяют freebsd, а не что-то с linux.

Comment: Даже если продажа и возможна, вряд-ли кто-то купит такой продукт из-за наличия открытых и бесплатных решений.

Comment: сенсорные телефоны до андроида были с форками фряхи, пс4 сейчас работает с форком фряхи, всё покупали и покупают. я пытаюсь понять, почему нельзя было использовать тот же набор программ, но с ядром linux, а не bsd-kernel.

Comment: Когда покупают телефон, то покупают не ПО, а устройство. Отдельно закрытое ПО (при наличии открытой и бесплатной альтернативы) вряд-ли кто-нибудь будет покупать.

Comment: вопрос не об этом, но всё же покупают. платные форки фряхи покупают, хоть и мало. вопрос о лицензии, мешает ли gplv2 делать это всё с линуксом вместо бсд?

Comment: GPL обязывает предоставлять исходники и разрешать дальнейшее распространение, далеко не всем это нравится

Comment: @Глеб, про Symbian слышали? Это ОС **первых** сенсорных телефонов.

Comment: @andreymal, в версиях лицензии есть существенные различия. Ваш комментарий ничего не проясняет. Что касается ядра, то у него лицензия версии 2, а работать с ядром можно по-разному.

Comment: @0andriy любая версия обязывает предоставлять исходники и разрешать дальнейшее распространение, что здесь непонятного?

Comment: @0andriy товарищ говорит, что закрытые форки открытого софта покупать не будут, я вспоминаю вагон сенсорных телефонов (которые держал в руках) до андроида на фряхе. Из "открытого" там в разделе "about" написано, что "есть программы под лицензией BSD". Исходя из этого я вообще не понимаю каким боком тут симбиан. Если это воспоминания молодости, то у меня и раскладушки от motorola были, и что?

Comment: RHEL как пример для десктопа и сервера. А вот для мобильных устройств, непонятно. Huawei сейчас без системы ) можно продать им

Comment: @andreymal, исходники чего?

Comment: @0andriy ядра. Для программ, которые запускаются на линуксе, GPL-лицензию у этого самого линукса обмазали пачкой исключений, поэтому проприетарное закрытое ПО на линуксе существовать может

Comment: В общем, отвечая на вопрос «Позволит ли gplv2 закрыть исходный код остальной системы» — да, позволит, так делает тот же андроид например; отвечая на вопрос «почему в таких решениях обычно применяют freebsd» — потому что не хотят делать ядро открытым.